# Something similar to Debug.Print in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to learn VB.Net coming off from experience using VBA. I was wondering if there was something similar that uses the "Debug.Print" from VBA in VB.Net. Also is there also something that is similar to the immediate window that exists in VB.Net? I was also looking for that too.

Comment: `Debug.Print` is [System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debug.print), the Immediate Window is a Visual Studio tool and it's called, wait for it..., [Immediate window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/immediate-window). You can use `Console.WriteLine()` instead of `Debug.Print()`, to print to the [Output Window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/output-window). based on the configuration and your preference.

Comment: The advantage of calling methods on `Debug` rather than `Console` is that they are ignored in a Release build.  That means you can leave them in your code for later and they won't affect a Release build at all.  The disadvantage is that the results don;t always show up immediately, where `Console` methods do.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is yes, there is an immediate window.

More interesting? The same key in Access/VBA (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>) will in fact launch the immediate window for you! (So yes to the immediate window, and same key (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>) to show it).

So this allows a "similar" approach in VB.NET

```
In VBA:
Debug.print "Hello"

In vb.net
Debug.print ("Hello")
```

Just keep in mind that When you using `debug.print` in VB.NET, you have use `()` for the expression. So parentheses `()` are requied. (In VBA that was optional).

ONE MORE very important tip:

By default, `debug.print` output NOT directed to the immediate window.

So, while in VS, go Tools → options. On the left pane choose "Debbuging", and then output window. In that area, check this box:

[image: finger pointing to box that should be checked]

So, once you do this?

During debugging, the immediate window should appear. (If not, then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>g</kbd>).

The Windows unfortunately does hide When you stop debugging, but you CAN hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>g</kbd> again.

And WHAT VERY FEW VB.NET folks know that VBA Access folks know?
You can in the immediate window even while not debugging, type in a code call such as:

[image]

VS will flip into debug mode, and call/run that code! So you can even call + use subs and functions you created (or built in ones) without EVEN being in debug mode (this is exactly what long time VBA developers do, and VB.NET supports this wonderful approach to development.

This great idea from VBA is thus avaialble in VB.NET, and few seem to know this great tool.

It not "quite" as fluid and easy as the immediate window in Access we all come to know and love, but checking the above box, and using the "long time" <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>g</kbd> key to open/show the immediate window goes a VERY long way and lays out a nice welcome mat of helping VBA developers making the jump to VB.NET.

In addition to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>g</kbd>, you can display the window by going from the IDE to Debug → Windows → immediate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
#If DEBUG Then
    'do something
#End If
```

This is ignored in Release build.